# Split and Merge values of columns of a table

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have my output data in following given format,

```
select 
trans_store_id as TRANS_WAREHOUSE_NAME, 
demand_store_id as DEMAND_WAREHOUSE_NAME, 
item_id as ITEM_NAME, 
NVL(transfer_qty,0) as TRANSFER_QTY 
from ORDER_DTL
WHERE gnum_isvalid=1




col1     col2    col3    col4
A        B       item1   500
A        C       item2   200
C        B       item1   300
```

I wanted to get data in following format,

```
col1     col2     col3     col4 
A        item1    500      0
B        item1    0        500
A        item2    200      0
C        item2    0        200
C        item1    300      0
B        item1    0        300
```

Kindly excuse lack of queries because i have no idea where to start. Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand what you want. Give us the table structures and tell us exactly what you trying to acheive

Comment: @SaggingRufus Kindly see the updated query.

Comment: @SaggingRufus . . . Compare the first row in the first table to the first two rows of the second table.

Comment: @GordonLinoff easier to see with the addition of the query. Before that, all anyone could do is guess.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use `union all`:

```
select col1, col3 as col2, col4 as col3, 0 as col4
from t
union all
select col2, col3, 0, col4
from t;
```

You have edited the question.  You can use a CTE:

```
with t as (
      select trans_store_id, demand_store_id, 
             item_id, NVL(transfer_qty, 0) as transfer_qty 
      from ORDER_DTL
      where gnum_isvalid = 1
     )
select trans_store_id, item_id, transfer_qty, 0 as other_qty
from t
union all
select demand_store_id, item_id, 0, transfer_qty as other_qty
from t;
```

Comment: how are you even able to answer this with such little information?

Comment: He's 576k, he can :)

Comment: @SaggingRufus . . . The answer seemed obvious.

Comment: I guess, what I am getting at is I can't even tell what he expects in each column.

Comment: Thanks, Worked just as expected.

Comment: @GordonLinoff Just a doubt, Exactly how many tables can i use as CTE in my query before query starts lagging. I already have 3 tables reworked just like this and the final table with joins might get huge.

Comment: @unkn0wn . . . This addresses the question that you asked (and appears to have answered it).  If you have another question, it is appropriate to ask another question.  Be clear if the question is about performance versus functionality.

Comment: @unkn0wn It depends on way more factors than a number of tables.  Calculations you're doing, functions you're using, number of rows, indexing, non-clustered indexes (usual and unavoidable problem with CTEs... can be fixed by using indexed views instead, if it really slows it... usually will with a massive amount of rows), types of joins... you can use the Query Analyzer to determine the parts of your queries that are slowing it up.

Comment: @justiceorjustus Thanks for giving me a brief, although at the time being i am summing up thousands of rows in hundreds and using full outer join (4-5 columns per table). Guess i'll look into it before my db table explodes.